# I have a problem with installing the calendar in my ionic angular app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm, calendar, dependencies

Quite easy. I need to create a project; write a calendar/schedule app which shows(and is editable) the schedule/division of professor in my institute up to daily view.

First Question, do you have better ideas, ways or software then me to code it?

Second:

- I installed a new fresh ionic app via "ionic start scheduleapp blank"
- choose angular
- cd file
- npm i angular-calendar angular-calendar-week-hours-view @angular/animations

and here already i get the following error:

```bash
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ER*your text*R!
npm ERR! While resolving: sched@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@15.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"^15.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"6.1.10" from @angular/animations@6.1.10
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   @angular/animations@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/animations@">=5.0.0 <7.0.0" from angular-calendar@0.23.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/angular-calendar
npm ERR!     angular-calendar@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (angular-calendar-week-hours-view)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\...
```

thats it.
luv you guys for helping me, you know how much apprechiated it is!?
Jonas I F

tried to google it, didnt find. now im here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First question:**

This calendar is pretty good for ionic: `ion2-calendar` ([documentation](https://github.com/HsuanXyz/ion2-calendar)).

Check it out to see if it's useful for your needs.

Install it with `npm install ion2-calendar moment --legacy-peer-deps`

**Second:**

Use

```
npm i angular-calendar angular-calendar-week-hours-view @angular/animations --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: Awesome! like this it worked. I tried it also before with --legacy... but that didnt help.

Comment: Now im stuck again... I just finished my apprentiseship and it is all new. All alone its hard. I need a working turtorial or what can i do?